# Is Order-preserving encryption part of the functional encryption family?

Tags: terminology, functional-encryption, order-preserving

I believe I know quite well OPE and ORE, but I'm unsure about what family to put them in. Can we consider them as a sub family of Functional Encryption, like Attribute Based Encryption or Inner Product Encryption or are they a new paradigm of their own ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, order-preserving encryption is not a subclass of [functional encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/543.pdf) as [usually defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_encryption), that is with public-key encryption.

Argument: In such functional encryption, encryption uses a public key. But we can't have secure public-key order-preserving encryption, because knowledge of the public key allows adversaries to encrypt, and ability to encrypt combined with the order-preserving property allows to decipher by dichotomy.

As noted in comment, that argument does not apply to Secret Key Functional Encryption, a notion I'm unfamiliar with. So I reserve my opinion on if OPE can be obtained in the framework of SKFE.

Comment: [Secret-key functional encryption is a thing.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1018) So while I agree with your conclusion, your argument doesn't quite track.

Comment: @Maeher I was going to comment that... FE for inner product suffers from more or less the same problem fgrieu pointed out: given a functional key for a hidden vector $v$, if one is able to encrypt several vectors $u_i$ by themselves, then they can decrypt several inner products $u_i \cdot v$ and then recover $v$ by linear algebra... So this type of FE for inner product is also secret key FE.